# xpath: //tag[@attr] vs. //tag[attr]

Tags: xml, xpath

Xpath question:

When to use @ with an attribute and when not to. Does it matter? What is the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `//tag[attr]` you are selecting all `tag` elements that have at least one child **element** named `attr`. On the other hand, when using `//tag[@attr]` you are selecting all `tag` elements that have an **attribute** named `attr`.

In sum, you use `@` everytime you want to select an attribute. It does matter, because omitting it would select nodes or elements, instead of attributes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to an attribute, you *must* use `@`, otherwise you are referring to an *element* of that name!